# Is there any way to improve this C bitwise function mathematically?

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I was trying to find a function that fit the following formula:

```
f(0,0) = ( 0, 1)
f(0,1) = ( 2, 3)
f(0,2) = ( 4, 5)
f(0,3) = ( 6, 7)
f(0,4) = ( 8, 9)
f(0,5) = (10,11)
f(0,6) = (12,13)
f(0,7) = (14,15)
f(1,0) = ( 1, 2)
f(1,1) = ( 1, 3)
f(1,2) = ( 5, 6)
f(1,3) = ( 5, 7)
f(1,4) = ( 9,10)
f(1,5) = ( 9,11)
f(1,6) = (13,14)
f(1,7) = (13,15)
f(2,0) = ( 3, 4)
f(2,1) = ( 3, 5)
f(2,2) = ( 3, 6)
f(2,3) = ( 3, 7)
f(2,4) = (11,12)
f(2,5) = (11,13)
f(2,6) = (11,14)
f(2,7) = (11,15)
```

I ended up with the following:

```
pair f(int a, int b){
    int k = (b >> a << (a+1)) + (1<<a);
    pair p = {k - 1, k + (b%(1<<a))};
    return p;
};
```

There is a problem, though: the modulus operator is not implemented on the architecture I'm aiming and is, thus, making the code slow. Is there any solution that doesn't use it?

There is a snippet to quickly test the formula:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct pair_ { int x; int y; } pair;

pair f(int a, int b){
    int k = (b >> a << (a+1)) + (1<<a);
    pair p = {k - 1, k + (b%(1<<a))};
    return p;
};

int main(){
    pair correct[4][16] = {{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9},{10,11},{12,13},{14,15},{16,17},{18,19},{20,21},{22,23},{24,25},{26,27},{28,29},{30,31}},{{1,2},{1,3},{5,6},{5,7},{9,10},{9,11},{13,14},{13,15},{17,18},{17,19},{21,22},{21,23},{25,26},{25,27},{29,30},{29,31}},{{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{3,7},{11,12},{11,13},{11,14},{11,15},{19,20},{19,21},{19,22},{19,23},{27,28},{27,29},{27,30},{27,31}},{{7,8},{7,9},{7,10},{7,11},{7,12},{7,13},{7,14},{7,15},{23,24},{23,25},{23,26},{23,27},{23,28},{23,29},{23,30},{23,31}}};

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<8; ++j)
            printf("f(%.2d,%.2d) = (%.2d,%.2d) | Correct: %d %d\n",
                i,
                j,
                f(i,j).x,
                f(i,j).y,
                f(i,j).x == correct[i][j].x,
                f(i,j).y == correct[i][j].y);

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Lookup tables are quick and easy if you have the space.  If the input space is as limited as presented in the OP, then a LUT is hard to beat.

Comment: What is LUT? Anyway, lookup tables are not an option since that function should work for arbitrary values. The point is, how do I get rid of the modulus? Is there any trick that would work there?

Comment: Ah of course, misunderstood what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Shifting may be faster and with less side-effect using `unsigned` rather than `int`.  2) Shifts > 15 should consider `unsigned long` rather than `unsigned` as `int/unsigned` is only certainly at least 16 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the modulus you are talking about is.

```
b % (1u << a)
```

Then you are in good shape because it's always by power of 2.  This expression is equivalent to:

```
b & ~(~0u << a)
```

The shift should be pretty fast.  If you're using a processor with no barrel shifter, it might be faster to use a lookup table:

```
b & mask[a]
```

Define `mask` as

```
static unsigned mask[] = { 
  ~(~0u),
  ~(~0u << 1),
  ~(~0u << 2), 
  ~(~0u << 3), 
  ~(~0u << 4), 
  ... skipping some entries
  ~(~0u << 30), 
  ~(~0u << 31), 
};
```

Comment: The better way to write this is `b & ((1<<a)-1)`.

Comment: @R..  Why is it better?  It assumes 2's complement math, so it's less portable.  And it requires exactly the same number of instructions.

Comment: @Gene Where is the assumption of twos complement? There are no negative numbers involved. Positive numbers are required to follow binary arithmetic.

Comment: @Gene: No, quite the opposite. Use of `~0` assumes twos complement, **and invokes undefined behavior** as you used it in that case: you're left-shifting a negative value. In other cases, `~0` might even be a trap representation. Portable C code should aim never to use operators that are defined on the representation (`&|^~`) except with unsigned arguments or where the argument and result must both be positive. Sticking to operators defined in terms of value is much better.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a problem, though: the modulus operator is not implemented on the architecture I'm aiming and is, thus, making the code slow. Is there any solution that doesn't use it?

If this is the only modulo operator

```
b % (1<<a)
```

it can be replaced with

```
b & ((1<<a)-1)
```

---

```
pair f(int a, int b){
    int k = (b >> a << (a+1)) + (1<<a);
    pair p = { k - 1, k + (b & ((1<<a) - 1)) };
    return p;
};
```